# Sqlite database not working on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created one application which using sqlite database.For first some time i have tested it on to the simulator .It was working fine on the simulator it shows the path of document directory:

```
Library/Application support/iPhone simulator/5.1/Application/UUID/document/database.sqlite
```

When i put it into the device it is showing following path:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/60534394-66B0-4A83-BAFE-5F48FBD17FF6/Documents/database.sqlite
```

It is showing warning that:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while inserting data. 'no such table: tableName'
```

What is the way to overcome this? Should i copy the database file in my application directory?

Comment: Why downVote ? My question seen to be proper and clear .I don't understand who  downvoted this for what reason.This is not encouraging at all.

Comment: I didn't down vote it :)

Comment: Yes, the database (if preconstructed) must be copied from the bundle into your app's working directory.  If not preconstructed you must have "first time through" logic somewhere to construct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  can use this code:

```
- (void)SaveAction {

NSString * databasefile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@\"SavedPapers\" ofType:@\"db\"];

sqlite3 *database = NULL;

// Open the database and return a database identifier variable
if (sqlite3_open([databasefile UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
// Create and prepare template insert statements (one for each field we want to save)
const char * SaveCommand = \"insert into papers values(?, ?, ?, ?)\";

if ( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, SaveCommand, -1, &SaveCommand_stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
NSAssert1(0, @\"Error while creating save statement. '%s'\", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
// Insert the data into the save statement
sqlite3_bind_text(SaveCommand_stmt,1,[currentTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(SaveCommand_stmt,2,[currentAuthor UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(SaveCommand_stmt,3,[currentSummary UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(SaveCommand_stmt,4,[currentLink UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

// Execute the SQLITE command
if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(SaveCommand_stmt)) {
NSAssert1(0, @\"Error while saving data. '%s'\", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@\"Save\" message:@\"Error saving  paper to database... :(\" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@\"OK\" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
[errorAlert release];
} else {
UIAlertView * GoodAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@\"Paper Saved!\" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@\"OK\" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[GoodAlert show];
[GoodAlert release];
}
// Reset the command contents and close the database
sqlite3_reset(SaveCommand_stmt);
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

i think hope is useful.

Answer (score -2):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while inserting data. 'no such table: tableName'

Use a valid table name.

It seems that you've DB with the table you're trying to inserting the data but the referencing DB is old. What you need to do is to select your DB from XCode, `press DELETE Key` and choose `Remove Reference`, **now again add your DB**, **also clear (DELETE) that `App` from simulator**. And run again!

This may solve your problem.